# LongPoll от вк апи

Tags: javascript, long-poll, vkontakte-api

Доброго времени суток. Объясните, пожалуйста.

Вот в скрипте php, настроенный на бесконечный цикл вызываю я сначала метод messages.GetLongPollServer, потом присоединяюсь к longpoll, страница грузится до 25 секунд или пока не получит событие.

Для проверки отправляю сообщение, все приходит, все работает. потом вызываю messages.GetLongPollHistory. Тоже работает. Там дальше идет обработка события в скрипте и опять цикл по новой.

У меня такой вопрос: нужно обрабатывать все события, а вот что делать если сообщение пришло во время обработки другого события, ведь оно не попадает в подключение long poll и я его не могу достать и обработать, что делать в таком случае?

Вот алгоритм:

`while(!$stop) {`

1. `messages.getLongPollServer`
2. `Подключение к long poll`: 
       `http://{$server}?act=a_check&key={$key}&ts={$ts}&wait=25&mode=2` (тут страница грузится 25 секунд, или пока не придет событие)
3. `messages.getLongPollHistory`
4. обрабатываем события
5. проверяем, нет ли команды остановки

`}`

Answer (score 1):

При передаче параметра `ts` вы задаете границу, после которой необходимо возвращать сообщения.

Например, результат запроса к LongPoll серверу:

`{ ts: 934518069, updates: [] }`

Необходимо сохранить `ts` в переменную и передавать при следующем запросе. В описанной вами ситуации, ВК поймет, что последнее событие, обработанное программой - `934518069` и нужно вернуть события, произошедшие после него.